# Clearing elements inside a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, list

I'm trying to clear elements in a ul list before its populated i.e. want to refresh (delete and load) a ul list everytime using ajax calls, but for some reason its not working, the code is as below

```
<div id="activitycontainer"> <ul id="activitylist" style="list-style: none;padding:0; margin:0;"> </ul> </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                autoRefreshCommentsHomePage()
            }, 5000);
        });
        function autoRefreshCommentsHomePage() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'GetActivity.sc',
                success: function(data) {
                    $(#activitylist).empty();
                    var resultStr = data;
                    var str = '';
                    var temp = '';
                    var ele = resultStr.split('@!@');
                    var arrayLength = ele.length;
                    for (var i = 1; i < arrayLength - 1; i++) {
                        temp = '<li><a href="#">' + 'User1' + ' @</a><span>&nbsp;</span><a>' + ele[i] + '</a></li>';
                        $(temp).appendTo("#activitylist");
                        i = i + 1;
                        temp = '<li><a style="color: black;">' + ele[i] + '</a></li>';
                        $(temp).appendTo("#activitylist");
                        temp = '<li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Comment</a><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#">Like</a><span>&nbsp;</span></li><br>';
                        $(temp).appendTo("#activitylist");
                        temp = '<br>';
                        $(temp).appendTo("#activitylist");
                    }
                    ;
                }
            });
        };
```

I'm clearing the `activitylist` ul using .empty function, when i run this what is happening is that no data gets populated in the ul.

If i remove the .empty function call, then the ajax keeps loading data every 5 seconds and my list keeps on growing but I want to basically clear the existing data and then load, this is not happening.

Please advise.

Comment: Try to use $('#activityList').innerHTML = ''; I don't trust to jQuery methods :)

Comment: Isn't this a typo: `$(#activitylist).empty();`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 is right, good catch! Not working because that will throw a JS error and stop execution of the function.

Comment: Thanks it was a simple syntax error :( my bad...I changed it to $("#activitylist").empty(); and it worked like a charm !! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to simply replace the full block of HTML, rather than removing/adding in two separate steps. Use the jQuery html() method for this.

```
    function autoRefreshCommentsHomePage() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetActivity.sc',
            success: function(data) {
                // Off topic, but you only need one var statement to declare all these
                var resultStr = data,
                str = '',
                temp = '',
                ele = resultStr.split('@!@'),
                arrayLength = ele.length;

                for (var i = 1; i < arrayLength - 1; i++) {

                    // Note the variable change to +=
                    temp += '<li><a href="#">' + 'User1' + ' @</a><span>&nbsp;</span><a>' + ele[i] + '</a></li>';

                    i = i + 1;

                    temp += '<li><a style="color: black;">' + ele[i] + '</a></li>';
                    temp += '<li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Comment</a><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#">Like</a><span>&nbsp;</span></li><br>';
                    temp += '<br>';

                }

                // Replace it all at once
                $('#activitylist').html(temp);
                ;
            }
        });
    }
    ;
```